# Does the "undefined" data type have only one value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) says that the `Null` data type have only one value:

> The Null type has exactly one value: null. See null and Null for more
> details.

But it doesn't say that the `undefined` data type have only one value:

> A variable that has not been assigned a value has the value undefined.
> See undefined and Undefined for more details.

So does the `undefined` data type have only one value or more than one value?

Comment: Essentially yes

Comment: I'm not sure what this means. `undefined` means it's not defined.

Comment: `null` means there's a specific value of _nothingness_. `undefined` means that it is not defined. Let's say, I have a friend "John" whose last name I don't know. John's last name remains `undefined` until it's specifically assigned a value. ["Cher"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cher), on the other hand, does not have an official last name, in which case her last name is `null`.

Comment: @DaveNewton the question is not what the value *means*. It is asking about the members of the type. E.g., the boolean *type* has exactly two members: `true` and `false`.

Comment: @BumhanYu see comment above.

Answer (score 4):

There is exactly one value of the type `undefined`. There are multiple things that can evaluate to `undefined`, like an unassigned variable, missing property, or [the `void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), among others:

```js
let x;
const obj = { };
const voidReturn = void 0;

console.log(typeof x, x);
console.log(typeof obj, obj);
console.log(typeof voidReturn, voidReturn);
```

---

For clarity there is a *value* `undefined` but there is also also the global property `undefined`. Unlike `null` it is actually part of `window`. So, if the literal `undefined` is used in code, it refers to that property:

```js
console.log("undefined" in window)
```

In the past it was possible to directly change it `window.undefined = 42;` which would then yield a strange result if used with `undefined === void 0`.  The global property has been made immutable to prevent this, however, it is still technically possible to work around the immutability and provide your own value for `undefined` if you shadow the property:

```js
function foo(undefined) {
  console.log(undefined === 42);
  console.log(typeof undefined);
  console.log(undefined === void 0);
}

foo(42);
```

By comparison the `null` is a language keyword and it *cannot* be overwritten in any fashion.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, go to [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-undefined-type): :-)

> **The Undefined Type**
>
> The Undefined type **has exactly one value**, called `undefined`. Any variable that has not been assigned a value has the value `undefined`.

So: The Undefined type has only one value.

---

I should note that there are two ways for a variable to *get* that value, so perhaps that's the confusion. The two ways are:

1. Because the variable has never had anything assigned to it (as the specification notes).
2. Because the variable has explicitly had `undefined` assigned to it (directly or indirectly).

Example:

```js
let a;
// `a` has the value `undefined` because it has never been assigned a value
console.log(typeof a); // undefined

let b = undefined;
console.log(typeof b); // undefined
let c = void 0;
console.log(typeof c); // undefined
let d = (() => { })();
console.log(typeof d); // undefined
const obj = {};
let e = obj.propertyThatDoesntExist;
console.log(typeof e); // undefined
```

`b`, 'c', 'd', and `e` have the value `undefined` because they've had that value assigned to them:

- `b` is assigned `undefined` by using the global `undefined` variable
- `c` is assigned `undefined` by using the result of the `void` operator, which is always `undefined`
- `d` is assigned `undefined` because it's assigned the return value of a function that never issues a `return` statement with a value; the function therefore returns the value `undefined`
- `e` is assigned `undefined` because it's assigned the value resulting from a property accessor expression (`obj.propertyThatDoesntExist`) for a property that doesn't exist; the result of a property access on a property that doesn't exist is `undefined`.

That's a reasonable list of ways variable may be assigned `undefined`; I'm sure there are more, it's just a sampling.

See also [VLAZ's subsequent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72913850/157247), which has some really good info in it. For instance, he makes the point that `null` is a keyword, but `undefined` is just a global variable.